# Paypal sandbox tests for third party payments using PayPal-PHP-SDK

Tags: php, paypal-sandbox, payment

The app needs to implement buyer-to-seller payments without involving marketplace account, meaning direct payments beetween buyer and seller. I've created two sandbox accounts to test how it may work and created [Third Party Payment](http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/payments/CreateThirdPartyPayment.html). It worked and said that the payment finished successfuly. But when I go to sandbox account page I can see NO activity, no money were paid and no operations in history. Why it happens and how can I test that this is a proper way for app needs? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While waiting for answers, it's now resolved. Obviously, given sample for [Third Party Payment](http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/payments/CreateThirdPartyPayment.html) is only about creating the payment without execution. So execution is the answer.